# Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.SubscriptionResources.GetResourceGroups() returning empty

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

For the code below, it is getting the search service if using Microsoft.Azure.Management.Search. It is not getting the resource group if using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources.

```
public static async Task<string> GetAdminKeysAsync(IAzureCredentialFactory credentialFactory, string subscriptionId, string serviceName, bool useAzureResourceManagerForAdminKeys)
    {
        if (!useAzureResourceManagerForAdminKeys)
        {
            var accessToken = credentialFactory.AcquireToken(Common.SystemConstants.Security.AzureManagementEndpoint);
            SearchManagementClient searchManagementClient = new SearchManagementClient(new TokenCredentials(accessToken))
            {
                SubscriptionId = subscriptionId
            };
            // Service found (see below code GetResourceGroupNameFromServiceName)
            string serviceResourceGroupName = GetResourceGroupNameFromServiceName(searchManagementClient, serviceName);
            var adminKeys = searchManagementClient.AdminKeys.Get(serviceResourceGroupName, serviceName);
            return adminKeys.PrimaryKey;
        }
        else
        {
            var tokenCredential = credentialFactory.AcquireTokenCredential(Common.SystemConstants.Security.AzureManagementEndpoint);
            var armClient = new ArmClient(tokenCredential, subscriptionId);
            var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
            // ResourceGroup not found
            var resourceGroups = subscription.GetResourceGroups();
            foreach (var resourceGroup in resourceGroups)
            {
                var searchServices = resourceGroup.GetSearchServices();
                foreach (var searchService in searchServices)
                {
                    if (searchService.Data.Name.Equals(serviceName))
                    {
                        var adminKeys = await searchService.GetAdminKeyAsync();
                        return adminKeys.Value.PrimaryKey;
                    }
                }
            }
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Service name {serviceName} can't be found from subscription {subscriptionId}.");
        }
    }
    
    public static string GetResourceGroupNameFromServiceName(SearchManagementClient searchManagementClient, string serviceName)
    {
        // Service found
        IPage<SearchService> searchCollection = searchManagementClient.Services.ListBySubscription();
        SearchService searchService = searchCollection.SingleOrDefault(azs => azs.Name.Equals(serviceName));
        string searchId = searchService.Id;
        Match matches = ResourceGroupIdPattern.Match(searchId);
        if (matches.Groups.Count < 2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Could not find resource group name in {searchId}.");
        }
        return matches.Groups[1].Value;
    }
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear: does `subscription.GetResourceGroups()` and `resourceGroup.GetSearchServices()` return any entries, or none at all?

Comment: Try changing `var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();` to `var subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscription();`and see if it works.

Comment: @AlexAIT GetResourceGroups does not return any entries.

Answer (score 1):

Please try by changing the following line of code:

```
foreach (var resourceGroup in resourceGroups)
```

to

```
await foreach (var resourceGroup in resourceGroups.GetAllAsync())
```

Comment: It still returned empty.

Comment: What kind of permissions (RBAC roles) the user executing the code has on the subscription?

Comment: Contributor, which works for the old code (!useAzureResourceManagerForAdminKeys block)